# How i can force JSON dates to not accept integer in java

Tags: java, json, rest

How i can force JSON date with Java to use a particular pattern and don't accept Integers, for example :

{
"birthday": 1
}

should not be accepted.

I tried

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private LocalDate birthday;

but still accept numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First create a class custom localDate deserializer

public class LocalDateDserializer extends StdDeserializer {

```
private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public LocalDateDserializer() {
    this(null);
}

public LocalDateDserializer(final Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
}

@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(final JsonParser jsonparser, final DeserializationContext context)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    final String date = jsonparser.getText();
    try {
        return formatter.parse(date).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Use the annotation
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDserializer.class)
private LocalDate birthday;